# Where to put build.gradle lines that I don't want to commit to version control?

Tags: gradle, version-control, build.gradle

I worked on a team project with a shared `build.gradle` in version control.

I want to add the following line to Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
```

But I don't want to modify the shared `build.gradle` file because others don't use Eclipse.

QUESTION: Where to put such personal Gradle customization?

[gradle.properties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html) could be the answer if it were not only for key-values.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this would be an additional build file that you check into your repo, but do not track.

For instance, your custom **`myBuild.gradle`** would look like this:

```
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
```

Add this file to your repo, but do **not track** it:

```
git add myBuild.gradle
git commit -m "add additional empty local-only build file"
git update-index --assume-unchanged myBuild.gradle
```

Then, in your main **`build.gradle`**, import your second build file:

```
apply from: 'myBuild.gradle'
```